Eslint rule to enforce only one usage of process.env
I have a webpack plugin in my Typescript project to define some custom variables like process.env.MY_VAR. But if I use this syntax process.env['MY_VAR'] they won't be reachable by the plugin so I need a eslint rule to throw an error when the second form is used, and suggest to use the first one only.
I've tried this:
"no-restricted-syntax": [
  "error",
  {
    "selector": "Literal[value=/process\\.env\\[/i]",
    "message": "Access process.env directly like process.env.MY_VAR"
  }
]

and this:
"selector": "Literal[value='process.env[']",

but something is missing.
